# What tool can atch convert multiple MP3 files + one image for all into one video per mp3 file

Tags: batch-file, video, mp3

Periodically I need to convert each track in a collection of MP3 files and one image for all of them into one video file per track.

currently I use a video editor on Windows which I have to run for each track.

Is there a tool or script which can automate this?

So far didn't find any.

Thank you.

Comment: Voting to move to superuser.com

Comment: Could you post the command tool you are using or what batch-code you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

Download [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) (**Static version**), find and copy *ffmpeg.exe* to `System32` folder.

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i "IMAGE.jpg" -i "AUDIO.mp3" -acodec libvo_aacenc -vcodec mpeg4 -shortest "CONVERT_TO_VIDEO.mp4" <br>
```